# Proving convergence of a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question is:

Show that the sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sqrt{n^4+2n^2}-1-n^2$ converge.

The previous 
assignment showed that $|\sqrt{1+2x}-1-x| \leq C |x|^2 \quad |x| \leq 1/4$.

Its hinted that you need to use this information, but I´m not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint, you have
$$
\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}-1-n^2 = n^2\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}-n^2\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}-n^2\cdot 1 = n^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}-\frac{1}{n^2}-1\right)
$$
so, "setting" $x\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{4}$, we have the existence of an absolute constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\left\lvert\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}-1-n^2\right\rvert \leq Cn^2\left\lvert\frac{1}{n^4}\right\rvert = \frac{C}{n^2}
$$
for every $n\geq 2$.

Now, conclude by comparison with the convergent series $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By the inequality, it follows that if $1/n^2\leq 1/4$, then
$$\frac{\left|\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}-1-n^2\right|}{n^2}=|\sqrt{1+2/n^2}-1/n^2-1|\leq \frac{C}{n^4}$$

Comment: A tad more than a "hint," I'd say, but +1.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sqrt{n^4+2n^2}-1-n^2=\\\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}-1-n^2)\dfrac{\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}+1+n^2}{\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}+1+n^2}=\\
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^4+2n^2-n^4-2n^2-1}{\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}+1+n^2}=\\
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{n^4+2n^2}+1+n^2}\\ \sim \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{n^4}+n^2}\sim \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{-1}{2n^2}$$

Comment: Your use of $\sim$ in the last two steps is wrong. The three series are not equivalent in the standard sense -- if they were, as they converge, that would mean they have the infinite sums have the same value.